# Calling Shell Methods from any Directory

Tags: shell

I have a shell script `command.sh` That has one function:

```
function helloworld {
    echo "Hello World, $1"
}
```

Can I call it in the terminal like:

`command helloworld Man`

Comment: Just for the terminology: This is not called a _method_, but it would be called a _function_, if it were syntactically correct. If this function is **defined** in your shell, you can invoke it no matter what your working directory is. However, functions in POSIX shell (as you indicated by your _shell_ tag) are declared **without** the `function` keywords. Your definition would work, say, in zsh or in bash (don't know about ksh), where you **can** optionally supply the word `function` for better readability.

Comment: Sorry about my mistake

Comment: There is another oddity in your question, which might be the reason of the confusion arised: You claim that you have a script called `command.sh`, but you never call it. Instead of `./command.sh`, you invoke a command named `command`, which is an internal command from your shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Make the script executable

First of all, go inside the directory where the script is saved and make sure that the script is **executable**. To make it executable run `chmod +x command.sh`.

Now to execute it, you have to run `source command.sh && helloworld Man`.

### Run the script as `./command.sh helloworld Man`

If you want to run the program by typing `./command.sh helloworld Man` you have to modify your script `command.sh` as follows:

```
function helloworld {
    echo "Hello World, $1"
}

$1 $2
```

### Run the script from any directory

Then if you want to run your command from any directory, move the script `command.sh` (the modified one that **I have written above**) into the `/bin` directory owned by the root. To run it you type:

```
command.sh helloworld Man
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still confused

Comment: Ask clear questions, and you will get clear answers.....

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot do it directly. But you can make the function available in your current session by sourcing the shell script. Then the function helloworld is accessible.

```
source command.sh
helloworld Man
```

Remember to source the file again when the function changed. So you might be better off with a one-liner

```
source command.sh && helloworld Man
```

Comment: But how can't I do something like this and it is already done before by git (As Example):
I can - whatever the directory I'm in - Write `git "init (As Example)"`

Comment: I don't see how this example is related to your question, since in any installation I am aware of, `git` is not a function.

Comment: git is an executable binary in you {$PATH} and not a function.

Answer (score 0):

The command named [`command`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html#top) basically tells the shell to **bypass** function- and  alias lookup. Hence if you write

```
command helloworld Man
```

the shell would search inside the `PATH` for a *file* of name `helloworld`. To execute the function (provided that it is defined inside your shell), call it as

```
helloworld Man
```